# Converting opencv c++ mat object into a 2d array

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to convert a opencv mat object into a 2d array using c++.
I have tried the following solution

```
 for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.cols; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = mat.at<float>(i, j);
        }
    }
```

but it the problem is now if I print the array `arr` and then print the `mat` object then they give two different outputs.

printing the array `arr`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.cols; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
```

printing the mat object:

```
cout<<mat<<endl;
```

they show different outputs.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working out"? It looks to me like you're building a vector of vectors just fine.

Comment: the thing is when i am printing the mat object and the vector they are not being the same.

 `cout<<mat<<endl`

and 

`for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++)
        cout << v[i][j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}`

they dont be the same output

Comment: Edit your question and show example output demonstrating the difference.

Comment: what is the `type()` of your Mat ? accessing it like `mat.at<float>(i,j)` only makes sense IF it actually contains float data and there is only a single channel (likely not so), so you are accessing the wrong memory

Comment: besides that, your dct code will overflow at the borders

Comment: Edit your question and provide output, and specify what you mean by 'it is not working'. You should clearly mention what are you expecting and what you get. Or if there are errors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: edited the question I think it's quite clear to understand now.